# image equal heights in bootstrap figure/row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a figure inside a column inside a row of col-md-6, so 2 images per row. Users can upload their own images and I am not cropping them to certain dimensions, they are uploaded at whatever dimensions they are.

On the frontend though this is causing an image with the height. The images aren't all the same height and it looks terrible. They should all be of equal height in the row without distorting the image or cropping the width.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6"><a href="/some-link">
            <figure class="meal-photo figure">
                <h1>Pic 1</h1><img
                    src="http://localhost:3000/userimg1.jpg"
                    class="img-fluid">
            </figure>
        </a></div>
    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6"><a href="/some-link">
            <figure class="meal-photo figure">
                <h1>Pic 2</h1><img
                    src="http://localhost:3000/userimg2.jpg"
                    class="img-fluid">
            </figure>
        </a></div>
    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6"><a href="/some-link">
            <figure class="meal-photo figure">
                <h1>Pic 3</h1><img
                    src="http://localhost:3000/userimg3.jpg"
                    class="img-fluid">
            </figure>
        </a></div>
    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6"><a href="/some-link">
            <figure class="meal-photo figure">
                <h1>Pic 4</h1><img src="http://localhost:3000/userimg4.jpg"
                    class="img-fluid">
            </figure>
        </a></div>
</div>

.img-fluid {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

I have not set any styles for `meal-photo` as of yet.

Comment: There is NO properly supported CSS method of equalising element heights if they do not share a parent. You will need Javascript.

Comment: Equally, if the images are different aspect ratios...what do you expect to happen? It seems you have unreasonable expectations.

Comment: If you don't need to support IE11, you can have an option to use object-fit of CSS. Try to take a look at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/
Hope it helps.

Comment: @Paulie_D, sorry, I didn't think in 2019 this would be unrealistic.

Comment: You will either need to set a height and then allow the width to be auto, or manipulate the images to fit your requirement as the users upload them.

Comment: @plumwd, I didn't want to crop the images to the exact size because I actually need a bigger one in another place, so I didn't want to upload the same image twice but rather use the same image and just resize it with css

Comment: If you manipulate the image when the user uploads you can make two copies. One for each purpose. If you don't want to do that, then set the width to be auto and specify the height. OR force the users to upload at the size you want.

Comment: What's your expected behavior when the figure image height is greater than its contained column? Do you want the image to be scaled with its ratio fixed or?

Comment: Yes, would like the image scaled with fixed ration.

Answer (score -1):

```
.img-fluid {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

What is telling this class actually. When you will give `height: auto;` the element will automatically adjust its `height` to allow its content to be displayed correctly. So, it will take height from your real image.

Now you have a way:
You don't need to use same size images. Just maintain the aspect ratio. `col-md-6` and `img-fluid` will adjust with your screen.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. I am using col-md-6 and .img-fluid yet the images are still not the same height.

Comment: Read my answer carefully bro.

Comment: Try to understand where you need to focus.